# How to drop a message in jms outbound adapter and reply my caller that I have sent message?

Tags: spring-integration

In my project, I have to send message to a queue destination. It is a fire and forget type. But as soon as i drop the message into the queue, i need to notify back to my caller that i have dropped the message.

I have tried `handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory).destination(queueName)`. But i could not attach any component after the handle. And i dont want my thread wait indefinitely also. Because, i have tried calling the above handle in a separate gateway, but my test was waiting indefinitely.

Any suggestions.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the channel before the outbound adapter a `publishSubscribeChannel` and bind a second subscriber to it that generates the reply and sends it.

Comment: You also can use `e -> e.advice()` as a second argument for the `.handle()` and utilize the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` for the same reason: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice

Comment: Thank you. I will try both of them.